# C++ Threading Pattern for Qt serial port

Tags: c++, multithreading, qt

My aim is to receive messages from a serial device without blocking the main thread (GUI) and to try to separate the platform-dependent logic (GUI and serial port) from the business logic (processing the messages) for ease of porting to other platforms

Context: I'm using Qt, and the QtSerialPort module. The message protocol is simple, 0xff is used to end each message.

I've found 4 solutions so far:

**Method 1:**

1. Using one thread to read a serial port and fill a buffer
2. Using another thread to read the buffer, extract valid messages (into another buffer? not sure how this will work yet)
3. Using yet another thread to parse the messages

**Method 2:**

1. Using one thread to read a serial port, and extract valid messages into a buffer
2. Using another thread to parse the messages

**Method 3:**

1. Using one thread to read a serial port, extract a valid message, and block till that message is processed, making use of QtSerialPort's internal read buffer to buffer incoming data

**Method 4:**

1. Using the main thread to asynchronously read serial port, extract a valid message, and for each message, spawn a new thread to process them

Methods 1,2 and 3 differ by the number of threads the general workload is split up into, though I don't know which is best.

I'm currently using method 4, which is horribly inefficient and doesn't work well on lower-end computers, due to the enormous number of threads being spawned, and every time I move or interact with the GUI, serial communication halts. Spawning a thread for each message also makes the order of the messages non-deterministic, which hasn't been a major problem so far...

Are there other methods, what are the pros (if any) and cons of each, and which is the best to use? Thanks!

EDIT: A problem with processing messages in the main thread is that interacting with GUI (even moving the window) would block the message processing function. Is there any way around this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think there are two main advantages that you can obtain by using multithreading:

1. Avoiding poor GUI performance due to the GUI-handling routines being held off by the serial port processing routine
2. (perhaps more important) Avoid loss of serial data caused by buffer overflow when the GUI routines hold off the serial-data-reading routine for too long.

You should only need to spawn a single thread.  Just have that thread read data from the serial port as it comes in (by connecting the QSerialPort's readyRead() signal to a slot that calls read() on the QSerialPort object), and then emit a signal (with a QByteArray argument) whenever it wants to send some serial data to the GUI.  Your main/GUI thread can receive the data via a QueuedConnection that will not block either the serial-thread or the main/GUI thread.

That's pretty much all there is to it; the only other thing to worry about is a clean shutdown.  Be sure to have another cross-thread signal/slot connection to the QThread's quit() slot, so that when it's time to quit, you can emit that signal and then call wait() on the QThread to wait for it to respond by going away.  Once wait() has returned you can safely delete the QThread object.

Comment: The problem is that processing the data has to be in another thread, as GUI could block this, so I can't send serial data to the GUI thread

Comment: If the data processing really needs to be done immediately, you could spawn a second thread that would be dedicated to that.  Are you 100% sure that it's necessary that the data must always be processed without delay, though?  What problems do you foresee happening if the data processing was held off for a few dozen milliseconds?

Comment: Ah, I understand now.  In that case either do all the data processing directly in the serial-port thread, or (if the processing is slow enough and/or the serial baud rate is fast enough that you're worried that the serial buffer might overflow while the serial-thread is busy processing the data) spawn a second thread for the data processing and let it communicate (still via QueuedConnection signals/slots) directly with the serial thread.  In either case you leave the GUI thread out of the loop entirely.

Answer (score 2):

You can avoid additional threads at all by simply relying on Qt event loop (so far the main thread, the one also handling the GUI to be clear, will be blocked only when a message is actually received by the serial port).

Otherwise if you want to completely handle serial port in a dedicated thread, then the solution is to implement a class deriving from `QThread` and then override the `run()` function with something like this:

```
void MyClass::run()
{
     QSerialPort port;

     // ... serial port initialization here

     // Connect signals/slots
     connect(&port, SIGNAL(readyRead()), this, SLOT(readData()));

     port.open();

     // Start a new message loop on this thread
     exec();
}
```

Where `readData` is a function implemented in `MyClass` for handling the received data. Since `port` is owned by the new thread (being created in `run()`) then its events will be handled by the thread itself (in a completely independent manner with respect to the main thread).

If you want at some point communicate something to the main thread (e.g.: you received something on serial which should cause a change in your GUI) then you can still use Qt's signals/slots. Simply implement a signal on `MyClass` and implement a slot on an object handled by the main thread (e.g.: your main form): then simply connect the signal for `MyClass` and the slot on your main form and you're done: signals/slots is **THE** solution for cross-thread communication in Qt.

Answer (score 0):

You could also avoid using any (additional) threads and take advantage of Qt [event loop](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Event_loop). Read about [events](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/eventsandfilters.html), [QioDevice](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/qiodevice.html); then Qt would pass your device file descriptor to its multiplexing loop (e.g. to [poll(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/poll.2.html)....); probably [QSocketNotifier](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qsocketnotifier.html) should work (on Posix) on a non-socket file descriptor like a serial device.

Details are probably OS specific